# sql datetime to get the first value of each day

Tags: sql, datetime

i have a sql server table named

```
Datetime
=======
column UserID(int), DateTime(datetime)
```

it stores attendance data for users.
each user have multiple datetime data for each day.
i need the first DateTime data for each day for a given user between a given date range then i need them to compare with a particular time say `08:00:00` to get the late attendance.
how this can be done?

Comment: Which database are you using? Datetime is a keyword in some databases. You need to use escape sequence to avoid getting a syntax error.

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention. edited now.

Answer (score 3):

If understood correctly here is the query for you

```
SELECT  UserID,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[datetime],111) as [AttendaceDate],
        MIN([datetime]) as [Date In], DATEDIFF(mi, MIN([datetime]), Convert(Datetime, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[datetime],111) + ' 8:00 am')) as [Minutes Late]
  FROM  TestTable
GROUP BY UserID, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[datetime],111)
```

Comment: finally i tried this 
================= 
SELECT UserID, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Dateime,111), MIN(Datetime) 
  FROM datetime 
  WHERE Datetime BETWEEN '1/1/2012' AND '1/5/2012' 
GROUP BY UserID, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Dateime,111) 
having MIN(CONVERT(VARCHAR, DateTime, 8)) > '08:00:00' 
and bingo. 
thanx a lot for your help.

Comment: sorry bro, not enough reputation. :S

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  UserID,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Dateime,111),
        MIN(Datetime)
  FROM  table
GROUP BY UserID, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Dateime,111)
WHERE   Datetime BETWEEN '1/1/2012' AND '1/5/2012'
```

Comment: it solves the above mentioned problem, thanx a lot for that. but sorry for not mentioning this earlier, i actually need to compare each datetime value with a particular time say 08:00:00 to get the late attendance which seems troublesome with this one. any idea bro?